# Derive a Trait for particular variants

Tags: enums, rust, traits

Let's say I have the following Enum

```
enum MyEnum {
  VariantA,
  VariantB,
  VariantC,
}
```

I can derive the PartialEq trait for the whole enum by doing so

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum {
  VariantA,
  VariantB,
  VariantC,
}
```

What I want to do, is derive the trait but only to particular variants and not the whole enum. Is that possible? (or does it even make sense?).

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. A trait derivation is a compile-time property of a type. A variant is a runtime property of a particular object. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Perhaps you should describe the behavior you're trying to achieve from this.

Comment: You use PartialEq or Eq when you want to compare two objects, let's say you want to check `MyEnum::VariantA == MyEnum::VariantB`.

Comment: The variants are types from other crates. Not all of them implement the PartialEq trait. But I'm happy to use it whenever it is there; and I would prefer to keep it as a single Enum.

Comment: In that case your best option is probably to manually implement `PartialEq` (`impl PartialEq for MyEnum`) such that it returns `false` whenever one of the unsupported variants is used as an operand.

Comment: @apemanzilla Yes that would be my last option. You can actually get the generated code from Rust and remove the problematic ones. But you'll have to redo it every time you update the enum with more variants.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a setup like:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct VarB{
    pub value: u32,
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum{
    VarA(VarA),
    VarB(VarB)
}
```

VarA comes from a different crate and you can't compile due to it not having derived PartialEq (or any other external trait).

You can solve that with the newtype pattern (assuming you have access to the relevent fields / accessors)

```
struct MyVarA(VarA);

impl PartialEq for MyVarA{
    fn eq(&self, other: &MyVarA) -> bool {
        self.0.value == other.0.value
    }

    fn ne(&self, other: &MyVarA) -> bool {
        self.0.value != other.0.value
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct VarB{
    value: u32,
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum{
    VarA(MyVarA),
    VarB(VarB)
}
```

further informations:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html

Answer (score 3):

> What I want to do, is derive the trait but only to particular variants and not the whole enum. Is that possible? (or does it even make sense?).

This doesn't really make sense.

Traits are implemented for *types*. An enum is a type and its variants are its values. Your question is equivalent to asking if you could implement a trait for some `String`s but not others.

If it is acceptable for unsupported variants to always return `false`, similar to how `f32`'s `PartialEq` implementation returns `false` whenever you compare a `NaN` value, then you can write that impl by hand:

```
impl PartialEq for MyEnum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &MyEnum) -> bool {
        use MyEnum::*;
        match (self, other) {
            // VariantA and VariantB are supported
            (VariantA(value), VariantA(other_value)) => value == other_value,
            (VariantB(value), VariantB(other_value)) => value == other_value,
            // Any other combinations of variants end up here
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must *not* implement `Eq` this way, since implementations of `Eq` may be assumed to be *total*, which this is not.